# What is a "fundamental type" in Rust?

Tags: rust

Somewhere I picked up the term "fundamental type" (and its attribute `#[fundamental]`) and just now I wanted to learn more about it. I vaguely remember it being about relaxing the coherence rules in some situations. And I think the reference types are such fundamental types.

Unfortunately, searching the web didn't bring me very far. The Rust reference does not mention it (as far as I can see). I just found [an issue about making tuples fundamental types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31682) and [the RFC that introduced the attribute](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md). However, the RFC has a single paragraph about fundamental types:

> - A `#[fundamental]` type `Foo` is one where implementing a blanket
>     impl over `Foo` is a breaking change. As described, `&` and `&mut` are
>     fundamental. This attribute would be applied to `Box`, making `Box`
>     behave the same as `&` and `&mut` with respect to coherence.

I find the wording fairly hard to understand and it feels like I need in-depth knowledge of the full RFC to understand this bit about fundamental types. I was hoping someone could explain fundamental types in somewhat simpler terms (without simplifying too much, of course). This question would also serve as an easy-to-find piece of knowledge.

To understand fundamental types, I'd like to answer these questions (in addition to the main "what are they even?" question, of course):

- Can fundamental types do more than non-fundamental ones?
- Can I, as a library author, benefit in some way from marking some of my types as `#[fundamental]`?
- Which types from the core language or standard library are fundamental?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Normally, if a library has a generic type `Foo<T>`, downstream crates can't implement traits on it, even if `T` is some local type. For example,

(`crate_a`)

```
struct Foo<T>(pub t: T)
```

(`crate_b`)

```
use crate_a::Foo;

struct Bar;

// This causes an error
impl Clone for Foo<Bar> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Foo(Bar)
    }
}
```

For a concrete example that works on the playground (that is, gives an error),

```
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Bar;

// This causes an error
// error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate
// can be implemented for arbitrary types
impl Default for Rc<Bar> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Rc::new(Bar)
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=140c6a56a4b28c0881d31170df4c4f22)

---

This normally enables the crate author to add (blanket) implementations of traits without breaking downstream crates. That's great in cases where it isn't initially certain that a type should implement a particular trait, but it later becomes clear that it should. For example, we might have some sort of numeric type that initially doesn't implement the traits from `num-traits`. Those traits could be added in later without needing a breaking change.

However, in some cases, the library author wants downstream crates to be able to implement traits themselves. This is where the `#[fundamental]` attribute comes in. When placed on a type, any trait not currently implemented for that type won't be implemented (barring a breaking change). As a result, downstream crates can implement traits for that type as long as a type parameter is local (there are some complicated rules for deciding which type parameters count for this). Since the fundamental type won't implement a given trait, that trait can freely be implemented without causing coherence issues.

For example, `Box<T>` is marked `#[fundamental]`, so the following code (similar to the `Rc<T>` version above) works. `Box<T>` doesn't implement `Default` (unless `T` implements `Default`) so we can assume that it won't in the future because `Box<T>` is fundamental. Note that implementing `Default` for `Bar` would cause problems, since then `Box<Bar>` already implements `Default`.

```
struct Bar;

impl Default for Box<Bar> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Box::new(Bar)
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed445f469ffa0de027161fb6adfacae6)

---

On the other hand, traits can also be marked with `#[fundamental]`. This has a dual meaning to fundamental types. If any type doesn't currently implement a fundamental trait, it can be assumed that that type won't implement it in the future (again, barring a breaking change). I'm not exactly sure how this is used in practice. In the code (linked below), `FnMut` is marked fundamental with the note that it's needed for regex (something about `&str: !FnMut`). I couldn't find where it's used in the `regex` crate or if it's used elsewhere.

In theory, if the `Add` trait were marked fundamental (which has been discussed) this could be used to implement addition between things that don't already have it. For example, adding `[MyNumericType; 3]` (pointwise), which could be useful in certain situations (of course, making `[T; N]` fundamental would also allow this).

---

The primitive fundamental types are `&T`, `&mut T` (see [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=88fca9d19e4d55db4362d948e780d58c) for a demonstration of all the generic primitive types). In the standard library, [`Box<T>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9578272d681c8691ca2ff3f5c4230b491bc1c694/src/liballoc/boxed.rs#L104) and [`Pin<T>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/e8f43b72eb2596f360004f6cdf9cdde4b9e789e1/src/libcore/pin.rs#L398) are also marked as fundamental.

The fundamental traits in the standard library are [`Sized`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/35ef33a89dfd8ff8c8a7b3c58fa7136bbcb2f1ed/src/libcore/marker.rs#L91), [`Fn<T>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/361791bb5fdd714bdc39f8af835f6468dd18331d/src/libcore/ops/function.rs#L64), [`FnMut<T>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/361791bb5fdd714bdc39f8af835f6468dd18331d/src/libcore/ops/function.rs#L143), [`FnOnce<T>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/361791bb5fdd714bdc39f8af835f6468dd18331d/src/libcore/ops/function.rs#L214) and [`Generator`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9ebf47851a357faa4cd97f4b1dc7835f6376e639/src/libcore/ops/generator.rs#L69).

---

Note that the `#[fundamental]` attribute is currently unstable. The tracking issue is [issue #29635](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29635).

Comment: Great answer! Regarding primitive types: there are only a handful generic primitive types: `&T`, `&mut T`, `*const T`, `*mut T`, `[T; N]`, `[T]`, `fn` pointer and tuples. And [testing them all](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9457ce9fba4a1de04b837e961201c65e) (please tell me if this code does not make sense) **it seems that references are the only fundamental primitive types**. Interesting. I would be interested in knowing the reasoning why the others are not, especially raw pointers. But that's not the scope of this question, I guess.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Thanks for the information on primitive types. I've added in your tests. As for the rationale about references vs pointers, check out [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1023#discussion-diff-27353727) in the RFC pull request.

Comment: The reference doesn't document unstable attributes, so that's why you didn't find it there.